# Convert Comma Separated Value to Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to convert comma separated string to Dictionary

```
string text = "abc,xyz,pqr";
```

Output should be `Dictionary<string, uint>` with key as string from text & value as number starting from 0.

I tried below but it gives error:

```
text.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToDictionary(split => split[0], 0))`
```

I'm also not sure how to give incremental value so I tried with constant hard coded value for all keys in dictionary as shown above but its giving error too.

Any help with either constant value for all keys or with incremental value using linq is much helpful!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are overloads of `Select()` which pass an index:

```
var dict = text.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select((str, idx) => new { str, idx })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.str, x => x.idx);
```

Comment: You need to cast to uint then. x => (uint)x.idx

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility of **duplicates** in your comma-separated values string? If so, outputting to a `Dictionary` leaves you vulnerable to the exception:

```
An item with the same key has already been added.
```

If duplicates *are* a possibility, then you might consider outputting to a [Lookup<TKey, TElement>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) as an alternative:

> A `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` resembles a [Dictionary<TKey,
>   TValue>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). The difference is that a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`
>   maps keys to single values, whereas a `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` maps
>   keys to collections of values.

Here's a solution similar to that in [the answer by @Corey Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150142/1497596) that makes use of [ToLookup()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate a `Lookup`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string text = "abc,xyz,pqr,linq,xyz,abc,is,xyz,pqr,fun";

        var lookup =
            text.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select((str, idx) => new { str, idx })
            .ToLookup(x => x.str, x => (uint)x.idx);

        foreach (IGrouping<string, uint> itemGroup in lookup)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item '{0}' appears at:", itemGroup.Key);

            foreach (uint item in itemGroup)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("- {0}", item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Item 'abc' appears at:
- 0
- 5
Item 'xyz' appears at:
- 1
- 4
- 7
Item 'pqr' appears at:
- 2
- 8
Item 'linq' appears at:
- 3
Item 'is' appears at:
- 6
Item 'fun' appears at:
- 9
```